# How do I view questions from today sorted by votes?

Tags: feature-request, sorting

The ability to sort by votes is neat, but it only shows old questions from all time. How do I get it to show the top voted posts from today (this week / month / year) instead?

Am I missing something or does this feature not exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a search and filter on `created`:

> [`created:2016-08-17..2016-08-17`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=created%3A2016-08-17..2016-08-17)

Unfortunately the shorthand `created:0d` doesn't work where as `created:1d` for questions from yesterday does. And so do the `created:1m` and `created:1y`. There is no shorthand for one week, so you'll need the full dates there as well.

See the [Searching help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for more options.

Comment: Thank you. `created:1d..` is book-markable and pretty close to what I want.